# Write file as callback in async recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote function, that loops through specified files. I would like to write the results after the function is finished.

simplified function:

```
var arrayOfMatchedTexts = []; // array to write as file

const funtion LoopThroughFiles (path, filer) => {

   var files=fs.readdirSync(path);

   for(files){
    
       if(file.isDir()) LoopThroughFiles(file, filter) //recursion
    
       else if(matchFilter){
          fs.readFile(filename, ...) //read file match text
          arrayOfMatchedTexts.push(match) //push match to global array
       }
        
  }
}
LoopThroughFiles('./path', '.html')
```

then I wanna **write file with arrayOfMatchedTexts[]**, but the thing is since it is recruisive async function, I can not handle callback propertly.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var arrayOfMatchedTexts = [];

async function LoopThroughFiles (path, filter) {
   var files=fs.readdirSync(path);
   for(const file of files){
       if(file.isDir()) await LoopThroughFiles(file, filter) // use await here 
       else if(matchFilter){
          const data = await fs.readFile(filename) // and here
          arrayOfMatchedTexts.push(data)
       } 
   }
}

LoopThroughFiles('./path', '.html').then(() => {
    // process arrayOfMatchedTexts here
})
```

If you don't like promise chaining, you can also try this:

```
(async() => {
    await LoopThroughFiles('./path', '.html')
    // process arrayOfMatchedTexts here
})()
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` doesn't return a promise by default

Comment: This is assuming the native promise. Anyways, I am just trying to put up an idea. The code won't work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I needed to await those two parts !